# (iOS)Project crashing after archiving but working fine in Release build

Tags: ios, widevine

I am working on a ios project which uses third party framework(widevine DRM framework). It is working fine in debug/release modes when it is tested but after archiving it is crashing. Inorder to make the framework work in debug/Release modes I had to set "dead code stripping" to NO and "symbols hidden by default" to NO.

Should I have to change something in the Build Settings for it to run properly after archive? What is the difference between running in Release mode and archive build?

Comment: Is it giving error when archiving or just crashing?

Comment: @Emre Onder It was crasing. I was able to solve it by changing build settings like "Strip Linked Product","Strip Style". Thank you for response